# How to mask particular segment of images while training CycleGAN?

Tags: deep-learning, gan, cyclegan

Say I am using a CycleGAN to generate **Zebra** from **Horse**. But for my case, there is also **deer** present in both of the images, and I don't want to change the **deer** from my input and keep them the same in output, only changing horse to zebra.

So, I guess I have to mask the deer in my training label so that the generator does not learn to change it. How can I achieve that? Does anyone have any idea? (Let's say I have deer/not-deer mask for all my training data)